# Threejs animating object not working

Tags: javascript, three.js

I started learning with Threejs to create a rotating 3D cube. I followed [this](https://www.solutiondesign.com/blog/-/blogs/getting-started-with-webgl-and-three-1) tutorial, but to animate the rotation of the object doesn't work.

Before this, I get an error that rotation is undefined. I solved it with the following code in animate():

```
var manager = new THREE.LoadingManager();
manager.onLoad = function() {
    root.render();
    requestAnimationFrame( root.animate );
}
```

Only now there is nothing happening. I also doesn't receive any errors. Does anyone know what is missing or what I do wrong?

```
App.cubeController = {

    camera: null, 
    scene: null, 
    renderer: null,
    mesh: null, 

    // Setup for render
    init: function(){

        // Development
        console.log('init cubeController');

        // Declare variables
        var root = this;

        root.scene = new THREE.Scene(); // Setting up the scene
        root.camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 70, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 1000); // Set dimensions of the stage

        var light = new THREE.DirectionalLight( 0xffffff );
        light.position.set( 0, 1, 1 ).normalize();
        root.scene.add(light);

        var geometry = new THREE.CubeGeometry(10, 10, 10); // Create the object
        var material = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial( { ambient: 0x050505, color: 0x0033ff, specular: 0x555555, shininess: 30 } );

        root.mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
        root.mesh.position.z = -50
        root.scene.add( root.mesh );

        root.renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
        root.renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
        $('body').append( root.renderer.domElement );

        window.addEventListener( 'resize', root.onWindowResize, false );


        root.render();
        root.animate();

    }, 

    // Update the state of each object in the scene
    animate: function() {

        // Development
        console.log("init Animate");

        var root = this;

        root.mesh.rotation.x += .05;
        root.mesh.rotation.y += .05;

        var manager = new THREE.LoadingManager();
        manager.onLoad = function() {
            root.render();
            requestAnimationFrame( root.animate );
        }



    }, 

    // Render the result
    render: function() {

        // Development
        console.log("init Render");

        var root = this;
        root.renderer.render( root.scene, root.camera );

    }, 

    // OnResize change camera aspect
    onWindowResize: function() {

        var root = this;

        root.camera.aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
        root.camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
        root.renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
        root.render();

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to call the `root.render` function after each animation is done. So call the `root.render` function in your `root.animate` function. Like this -

```
var root = this;

    animate: function() {

            // Development
            console.log("init Animate");

            requestAnimationFrame( root.animate );

            root.mesh.rotation.x += .05;
            root.mesh.rotation.y += .05;
            root.render();
        },
```

Also, i dont know why do you need `LoadingManager`. I dont think it should be used in the `animate` function which will be called repeatedly.

**Edit:** You have to define the `root` variable outside of the functions. You have defined this variable in every function. Instead you have to define it in the `CubeController`.

Comment: When I use above code I get an error: `Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'requestAnimationFrame' on 'Window': The callback provided as parameter 1 is not a function.` on line 50 that is: `requestAnimationFrame( root.animate );` What do we miss?